# Spring Batch - Reading file with data spanning on multiple lines having different format

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a job reading from an input file (delimited) where I have lines with different record type:
if record `type = A` I want to map to an `object ObjectA`, if record `type = B` I want to map to an `ObjectB`.`ObjectA` has an attribute that is a list of `ObjectB`.
In my input file, a record `type A` is followed by several record `type B`:

```
> AS;1111111;A;otherinfo
S;11111;B;otherinfo;otherinfo1;otherinfo2
S;11111;B;otherinfo;otherinfo1;otherinfo2
AT;1111112;A;otherinfo
S;11112;B;otherinfo;otherinfo1;otherinfo2
S;11112;B;otherinfo;otherinfo1;otherinfo2
```

Each returned item of my reader must be `ObjectA`.

I have implemented a `FlatFileItemReader` using a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` as `lineMapper`. This last has a `list of (2) LineTokenizer` and a `list of (2) FieldSetMapper` with specific matching for each type of line from input file.

And this works fine.

Now, in order to return each item of type `ObjectA` with related list of `ObjectB`, I'm trying to implement a custom `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` my reader above should delegate to... but I don't know how to manage the fact that `peek()` should `return ObjectA` or `ObjectB` based on the record type.
The logic would be: `if peek() returns ObjectA`, it's a new item so return the current, `if peek() returns ObjectB` this is related to the current item, so `read()` and `add ObjectB` instance to the list of `ObjectB` in current item.

Any advice on how to approach this multiline reader implementation?
Maybe the correct approach is the multiline-record described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#multiLineRecord) and not using a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is very specific as it combines having a single item that spans multiple lines and at the same time the reader could return different types of items.

I don't see an obvious way to do that with what Spring Batch offers out-of-the-box (other than using a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` with a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`, but this does not seem to work for you according to your description). So you would need a custom `ItemReader`  similar to the one described in this section: [Multi-Line Records](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#multiLineRecords).

Comment: I solved this way: 1. Make ObjectA and ObjectB extend LineItem that contains the record type; 2. Make SingleItemPeekableItemReader and FlatFileItemReader return LineItem;  3. Make each FieldSetMapper returns ObjectA or ObjectB accordingly; 4. In the implementation of SingleItemPeekableItemReader cast LineItem to ObjectA or ObjectB after checking the record type. Any comment would be very welcomed.